# Angular HTTP 302 Error: Trouble retrieving object from Spring Boot API

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I'm currently working on an Angular application where I'm attempting to retrieve a group name from the URL, which follows the format 'localhost:8080/groups/g/example'. In my Angular app.routing-module.ts file, I've configured the parameter 'example' as part of the URL. My objective is to fetch a corresponding group object from a Spring Boot backend based on this parameter. However, I've encountered an error in this process. It's important to note that this functionality operates smoothly when tested using Postman.

**ShowGroupPostComponent:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Group } from '../module/Group';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { GroupService } from '../services/group-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-group-post',
  templateUrl: './show-group-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-group-post.component.css']
})
export class ShowGroupPostComponent implements OnInit {
  group:Group = new Group("", "");

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,
              private groupService:GroupService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let groupName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('groupName');
    this.groupService.getGroupByName(groupName).subscribe((group) => this.group = group);
  }
}
```

**GroupService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable, of} from "rxjs";
import { Group } from '../module/Group';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GroupService {
  BASE_URL : string = "http://localhost:8080";
  url : string = "";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getGroupByName(name:String | null):Observable<Group>{

    if(name === null)
      return of(new Group("",""));

    this.url = this.BASE_URL + "/groups/g/" + name;

    return this.http.get<Group>(this.url);
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 302, statusText: 'OK', url:'http://localhost:8080/groups/g/example', ok: false, …}
error: {name: 'example', description: 'exampleDesc'}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/groups/g/example: 302 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 302
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/groups/g/example"
[[Prototype]] : HttpResponseBase
```

Despite successful trials using Postman, I'm encountering this error when attempting to retrieve the group object from the Spring Boot backend within my Angular application. I'm seeking guidance or insights into potential resolutions for this issue.